SSRS/Report Builder Cascading Parameters using Multi-value
I have a report that uses two main queries to get two tables. I also have 5 parameters (3 of which are cascading): StartDate, EndDate, JourneyTag, JourneyName, URL. My datasource is a Power Bi semantic model, which is why I haven't been able to find a lot of information on why this problem might be happening.
Basically, the Select All option for my cascading parameters isn't working properly. When I Select All for Journey Tag, the highest level of parameter, the Journey Name parameter blanks out instead of showing all Journey Names, and I can't make any parmeter selection. The same thing happens to URL parameter when I select Journey Name. When I try to select "Select All" for the URL parameter, both of my tables are always blank which is incorrect. How can I fix this?
Here are my two main queries that give me my two tables:
Query 1:
    EVALUATE
    CALCULATETABLE (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Email Com + Inter'[Date],
    'Email Messages'[Journey Name],
    'Email Messages'[Journey Tag],
    'Email Com + Inter'[URL],
    'Email Com + Inter'[Probe_Name],
    FILTER (
        'Email Com + Inter',
        AND ('Email Com + Inter'[URL] = (@Url),
            AND (
                'Email Com + Inter'[Date] >= @StartDate,
                'Email Com + Inter'[Date] <= @EndDate
            )
           )
        ),
    FILTER('Email Messages',
        AND('Email Messages'[Journey Tag] = (@JourneyTag),
        'Email Messages'[Journey Name] = (@JourneyName)
        )
      ),
    
    "Total Clicks", [Total Clicks],
    "Unique Clicks", [Unique Clicks]
       )
      )

Query 2:
    EVALUATE
    CALCULATETABLE (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Email Com + Inter'[Date],
    'Email Messages'[Journey Name],
    'Email Messages'[Journey Tag],
    'Email Com + Inter'[URL],
    'Email Com + Inter'[Probe_Name],
    FILTER (
        'Email Com + Inter',
        AND ('Email Com + Inter'[URL] = (@Url),
            AND (
                'Email Com + Inter'[Date] >= @StartDate,
                'Email Com + Inter'[Date] <= @EndDate
            )
        )
        ),
    FILTER('Email Messages',
        AND('Email Messages'[Journey Tag] = (@JourneyTag),
        'Email Messages'[Journey Name] = (@JourneyName)
        )
    ),
    
    "Total Clicks", [Total Clicks],
    "Unique Clicks", [Unique Clicks]
     )
    )

And here are the queries behind my three cascading parameters:
JourneyTag:
    EVALUATE 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        'Email Messages'[Journey Tag],
    FILTER(
    'Email Com + Inter',
    'Email Com + Inter'[Date] >= @StartDate &&
    'Email Com + Inter'[Date] <= @EndDate
        )
    )

JourneyName:
    EVALUATE 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
      'Email Messages'[Journey Name],
    FILTER(
    'Email Messages',
    'Email Messages'[Journey Tag] = @JourneyTag &&
    'Email Messages'[Journey_Action_ID] IN 
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES('Email Com + Inter'[Journey_Action_ID]),
            FILTER(
                'Email Com + Inter',
                'Email Com + Inter'[Date] >= @StartDate &&
                'Email Com + Inter'[Date] <= @EndDate
            )
        )
      )
    )

URL:
    EVALUATE
    VAR FilteredJourneyActions =
    CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES('Email Messages'[Journey_Action_ID]),
    'Email Messages'[Journey Name] = @JourneyName
        )
    RETURN
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        'Email Com + Inter'[URL],
        FILTER(
            'Email Com + Inter',
            'Email Com + Inter'[Journey_Action_ID] IN 
    FilteredJourneyActions
        )
    )

I tried changing = to IN (i.e. 'Email Messages'[Journey Name] = @JourneyName --> 'Email Messages'[Journey Name] IN @JourneyName), but I just got an error.
